Seaborn graph in streamlit does not let you customize theme
I would like to modify the theme of a seaborn objects graph displayed through streamlit. However, it seems that the graph only uses the standard theme, disregarding the .theme() part.
The following code in a ipython notebook
import seaborn.objects as so
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(100), 'y': np.sin(np.arange(100)/10)})

theme_dict = {**sns.axes_style("darkgrid"), "grid.linestyle": "--"}

so.Plot(df, x='x', y='y').add(so.Bars()).theme(theme_dict)

generates this graph:

while the equivalent code for streamlit:
import streamlit as st

import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def main():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

    theme_dict = {**sns.axes_style("darkgrid"), "grid.linestyle": "--"}

    df = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.arange(100), "y": np.sin(np.arange(100) / 10)})
    so.Plot(df, x="x", y="y").add(so.Bars()).on(ax).theme(theme_dict).plot()
    st.pyplot(fig)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


with streamlit run main.py generates the following in the browser:

without the theme. It does not matter if I move the .theme() further up in the chain.
Any suggestion on how to do this correctly?
streamlit                 1.38.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
seaborn                   0.13.2               hd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
seaborn-base              0.13.2             pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge


I think we can simply declare it with plt.figure() instead of fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1).
fig = plt.figure();        theme_dict = {**sns.axes_style("darkgrid"), "grid.linestyle": "--"};     df = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.arange(100), "y": np.sin(np.arange(100) / 10)});    so.Plot(df, x="x", y="y").add(so.Bars()).on(fig).theme(theme_dict).plot();st.pyplot(fig)

@r-beginners - thanks a lot, that worked! Any idea why?
